# HTTP500: SERVER ERROR when using ajax POST on server but not localhost

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a script that uses $.post to post things to my database. Everything works fine on XAMPP when I try with localhost. However as soon as I upload everything to my server I get an ERROR 500.

This is the javascript:

```
            $.post('processtask.php', {name: name, duration: duration, frequency: frequency, priority: num, process: 'add'}, function(data){
                $("#taskpriority").append('<li id='+data+' class="taskOrder list-group-item list-group-item-dark d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" draggable="true" style="display: block;"><i onclick="removeTask()" class="far fa-trash-alt"></i><strong>'+name+'</strong><span class="badge badge-dark badge-pill">'+num+'</span></li>').sortable({ placeholderClass: 'list-group-item' });
                $("#taskName").val('');
                $("#taskFrequency").val('Duration');
                $("#taskDuration").val('Frequency');
            });
```

This is the proccesstask.php page Im using to proccess the information.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['s_logged_n'] != true) header("Location: index.php");
    include('functions.php');
    require_once('dblink.php');
    header('content-type: application/json;');
    $currentDay = date("N");
    if($_POST['process'] == 'add'){
        $frequency = $_POST['frequency'];
        if ($frequency == 7){
            $done = 7 - ($frequency-$currentDay)-1 ;
        }else $done = 0;
        $query = 'INSERT INTO `tasks` (user, name, duration, priority, frequency, isdone) VALUES (:user, :name, :duration, :priority, :frequency, :done);';
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(':user', $_SESSION['s_id']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':name', $_POST['name']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':duration', $_POST['duration']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':priority', $_POST['priority']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':frequency', $_POST['frequency']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':done', $done);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $id = $dbh->lastInsertId();
            echo json_encode($id);
        }
    }
    if($_POST['process'] == 'updatepriority'){
        $query = 'UPDATE `tasks` SET `priority` = :priority WHERE `id` = :id';
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(':priority', $_POST['priority']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id', $_POST['taskId']);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $id = $dbh->lastInsertId();
            echo json_encode($id);
        }
    }
    if($_POST['process'] == 'remove'){
        $query = 'DELETE FROM `tasks` WHERE `id` = :id';
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id', $_POST['taskId']);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $id = $dbh->lastInsertId();
            echo json_encode($id);
        }
    }
    if($_POST['process'] == 'savetask'){
        $category = 'dark';
        $end = $_POST['start'] + ($_POST['duration']*25);
        $query = 'INSERT INTO `event` (week, day, category, start, end, duration, name) VALUES (:week, :day, :category, :start, :end, :duration, :name)';
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(':week', $_POST['week']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':day', $_POST['day']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':name', $_POST['taskname']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':category', $category);
        $stmt->bindValue(':start', $_POST['start']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':end', $end);
        $stmt->bindValue(':duration', $_POST['duration']);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $query = 'UPDATE `tasks` SET `isdone` = `isdone` + 1 WHERE `id` = :id';
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $id = $dbh->lastInsertId();
                echo json_encode($id);
            }
        }   
    }               
?>
```

Im currently testing with the "add" portion of the code, I put the entire code in case it was needed. Is it something to do with the config files on my server?

Comment: My guess is you are passing `null` value to a one of parameter

Comment: @SilentCoder but wouldn't I get the same error on localhost in that case? None of the parameters I'm passing are null when I test on localhost.

Comment: Check the error logs and please provide the actual error. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php (assuming it is a PDO error)

Comment: looking at the error logs I remembered I added fields to my tables that I forgot to add. Thanks!

Comment: Check your spelling, and make sure everything is correct. Online web servers tend to be case sensitive, whereas localhost environments are not. Also check if you are making a http request over a https connection anywhere.